# Replacement macro not working in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, replace, macros

I want to do automatic string replacement in Visual Studio 2008, using a macro. I have created the macro using the recorder (see code below) but it doesn't work (though in interactive mode the replacement works fine).

I want the substitution to be applied to the current selection in the current document. I am surprised to see the name of the file (`Text.txt`) explicitly appearing, so that the macro probably wouldn't work on another file, but it doesn't work anyway on that one.

Here is the macro source:

```
Sub Multiline()
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.Replace")
    DTE.Windows.Item("Text.txt").Activate()
    DTE.Find.FindWhat = "$"
    DTE.Find.ReplaceWith = "\n\n"
    DTE.Find.Target = vsFindTarget.vsFindTargetCurrentDocumentSelection
    DTE.Find.MatchCase = True
    DTE.Find.MatchWholeWord = False
    DTE.Find.MatchInHiddenText = True
    DTE.Find.PatternSyntax = vsFindPatternSyntax.vsFindPatternSyntaxRegExpr
    DTE.Find.ResultsLocation = vsFindResultsLocation.vsFindResultsNone
    DTE.Find.Action = vsFindAction.vsFindActionReplaceAll
    If (DTE.Find.Execute() = vsFindResult.vsFindResultNotFound) Then
        Throw New System.Exception("vsFindResultNotFound")
    End If
End Sub
```

For reference, the corresponding replacement dialog:

[image]

Any hint ? Why is this failing ?

Answer (score 0):

Got it, I was victim of a know issue in a Windows update, affecting Visual Studio.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2934830/marshaling-of-reflection-types-may-not-work-over-dcom-after-you-instal